# Angles inequality in a tetrahedron

Tags: geometry, inequality, optimization

Let $ I \in \triangle \text{ABC}$ of tetrahedron $ABCD$. Prove the
 inequality: $$\measuredangle ADB+\measuredangle BDC+\measuredangle CDA \ge \measuredangle ADI+\measuredangle
 BDI+\measuredangle CDI$$

---

Non-Euclidean geometry is very new for me. Help me please.

Comment: Since you mention non-Euclidean geometry, let's translate the problem a bit. Since all the angles have vertex $D$, we can place $D$ at the center of a (unit) sphere, and we can assume the edges meeting $D$ have length $1$; we can even take $I$ to be the point on ray $\vec{DI}$ such that $|DI|=1$. Thus, we have spherical triangle $\triangle ABC$ with interior point $I$, and the task is to show that $$|AB|+|BC|+|CA| \ge |AI|+|BI|+|CI|$$ Thinking about how you might prove a comparable relation for planar triangles could get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Euclidean geometry also works.

Prove: $\measuredangle ADB+\measuredangle BDC > \measuredangle ADI+\measuredangle CDI$

first to prove $\measuredangle ADB+\measuredangle BDC > \measuredangle ADC$,then extend $AI$ to $BC$, cross at $E$,  $\measuredangle ADB+\measuredangle BDE > \measuredangle ADE$,then you can do rest.